How to circumvent ImportError when invoking tikzplotlib?
Invoking
import tikzplotlib

gives
ImportError: cannot import name 'common_texification' from 'matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf' (C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_pgf.py)

Can someone tell me what is going on?

This issue has already been reported several times on github, for example
https://github.com/nschloe/tikzplotlib/issues/559

along with many other critical errors.
The development of the package tikzplotlib has been completely stopped, not even pull requests are accepted.
The use of tikzplotlib with matplotlib >=3.6 is next to impossible and the installation of matplotlib <3.6 is next to impossible as well (as of 2024).  [I lost several hours figuring out all that.]
It would only be fair that the package tikzplotlib is removed from the list of Python packages. Avoid it at all costs.

A workaround for me was the replacement of common_texification by _tex_escape in the beginning of tikzplotlib/_axes.py (code snippet at the end) .
Additionally, I had to make further tiny changes, such as rename legendHandles to legend_handles in tikzplotlib/_util.py and _ncol to _ncols in tikzplotlib/_legend.py, which were directly proposed by my debugger. Finally it worked for my examples, but also shows that tikzplotlib loses connection to updates.
#from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import (
#    common_texification as mpl_common_texification,
#)

from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import (
    _tex_escape as mpl_common_texification,
)

